# Make phpunit.xml in CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

**How to make phpunit.xml in CakePHP2.4?**

---

I made:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
     testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./app/Test/Case</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And

> cd /Project/ phpunit

And got an error

> Fatal error: Class 'CakeTestSuite' not found in
>   PROJECT_NAME\app\Test\Case\AllTestsTest.php on line 36

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how testing with Cake 2.x works, please refer to the Cookbook

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html

Cake 2.x ships with a graphical test runner, as well as a test shell. Both wrap the usage of PHPUnit, so that autoloading and other CakePHP specific stuff works properly in the testing environment.

Speaking of autoloading, that's why you are receiving the error, the Cake autoloader isn't available, and the classes that would include the missing test suite class aren't either.

Long story short, use the shell and everything should be fine: `Console/cake test app AllTests`

Comment: Or `Console/cake test Path/to/File.php` or `Console/cake test Test/Case/Path/To/Test.php`